# Javascript object property check if returned true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, velocity.js

Using a library called Velocity JS for animating: http://julian.com/research/velocity/

I am using it as follows:

```
 var velocity = new Velocity(element, {
                    translateX: 250,
                    complete: function() {
                       return true;
                    }
                }, 5);
```

What I am trying to do is **check if complete has returned true** on successful completion of the animation so that I can toggle the animation.

What is the best method for checking if it is true

```
if(velocity.complete() === true)
```

This returns undefined.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: The general principle of callbacks is handled very well in [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) You'll be mostly interested in the "restructe code" portion of the accepted answer.

Comment: Im trying to TOGGLE the animation with another click, so I thought checking if the first animation has completed would be the best way

Comment: Ah, so you want the `complete` function to toggle a state variable that indicates the program is ready to perform a reverse animation? That is indeed a slightly different problem.

Comment: Yes exactly, since Velocity JS doesn't use classes, it applies the animation directly to the element. So i need a way to toggle the animation back to where it was before (translateX:0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store the fact that the animation has completed, in order to read that information later based on user interaction (e.g., clicking a button), simply set a variable in an outer scope:

```
var animationComplete = false;

var velocity = new Velocity(element, {
                    translateX: 250,
                    complete: function() {
                       animationComplete = true;
                    }
                }, 5);
```

And read it when the user interaction happens:

```
$("#someButton").on("click", function() {
    if(animationComplete) {
        // do something only if the animation has completed
    }
});
```

It does not matter where you store that value (as a local or global variable, as a property on an object, etc.), as long as it's visible to the functions that need to read and set it.

Note that the return value of the `complete` callback is never used. The `complete` callback function object is passed into the `Velocity` constructor, and it is called later from inside of velocity.js's own code somewhere. Velocity.js probably does not expose (or even store) this return value anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You already pass the complete function, but `return`ing `true` is not so helpful in this case. Start the second animation when the complete function is called:

```
var velocity = new Velocity(element, {
    translateX: 250,
    complete: function() {
       // start another animation
    }
}, 5);
```

---

If you need to toggle animation on click or another event you have to store animation boolean outside somewhere, even in the dom element or using jQuery `data` method:

```
var $velocity = $("#velocity");

$velocity.data("animating", false);
$velocity.data("direction", "left");

$velocity.on("click", function () {

    if ($velocity.data("animating")) {
        return;
    }

    $velocity.data("animating", true);

    if ($velocity.data("direction") === "left") {
        var ml = -30;
        $velocity.data("direction", "right");
    } else {
        var ml = 30;
        $velocity.data("direction", "left");
    }

    $velocity.velocity({marginLeft:ml},{
        duration:500,
        complete: function () {
            $velocity.data("animating", false);       
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xE77/6/)

Comment: Im trying to TOGGLE the animation with another click on the same button, so I thought checking if the first animation has completed would be the best way